# Vite manifest not found at: C:\Users\HP\example-app\public\/build/manifest.json

Tags: laravel, manifest, breeze, vite

When i install breeze package in laravel
Vite manifest not found at: C:\Users\HP\example-app\public/build/manifest.json

Comment: just a quick google search let to this https://issueantenna.com/repo/laravel/framework/issues/42991

Comment: Remember to run `npm install && npm run dev`

Comment: Also read: [Vite manifest not found at: manifest.json in Laravel 9](https://devnote.in/vite-manifest-not-found-at-manifest-json-in-laravel-9/)

Answer (score 41):

According to the official Laravel documentation of installation Laravel Breeze [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits), after you have executed `composer require laravel/breeze --dev` and `php artisan breeze:install vue` (if you are using vue or can specify other desired stack), you need to execute these commands as well:

```
    npm install
    npm run dev
    php artisan migrate
```

But in my case, after I execute `npm install && npm run dev`, I am getting this error below:
[image]

This error in the terminal also will result in the same exception saying the Vite manifest not found. The error mentioned that they can't find 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'. To fix this, you can follow this [guide](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/UPGRADE.md) which will ask you to execute these commands below:

```
    npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
    npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

You also need to update your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
}
```

Finally, you can trigger this command below to build Vite and create the manifest file.

```
    npm run build
```

Comment: I spent hours trying to solve this problem. I followed your tip and it worked for me. Thanks for sharing @raja-asyraf.

Comment: Thank you, this solutions still working on Laravel 10

Comment: Thank you, "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
}  is all I needed.