# Laravel 9 / Bootstrap - Vite manifest not found at

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-5, vite

New to Laravel and I am having trouble getting bootstrap going with my project. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I will give steps to see if anyone can repro and advise. Thanks in advance

I started with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04

**1. Install PHP 8.1.2:**

`sudo apt install -y php php-common php-cli php-gd php-mysqlnd php-curl php-intl php-mbstring php-bcmath php-xml php-zip`

**2. Install Composer:**

`sudo apt install -y curl`

`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer`

**3. Create Laravel Project:**

`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist laravel-bootstrap`

`cd laravel-bootstrap`

**4. Install Laravel/UI & Bootstrap**

`composer require laravel/ui`

`php artisan ui bootstrap`

`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

`npm install`

`npm run dev`

When I run **npm run dev**, I get this message :

```
dev
vite

file:///var/www/laravel-bootstrap/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

If I run **php artisan serve** and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 I get the default Laravel page and it looks fine, but if I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/login, I get a **Missing Vite Manifest File** error message

screenshot of error : https://i.postimg.cc/Njzn2wBp/Screenshot-from-2022-08-18-00-11-28.png

Answer (score 2):

I had pretty same problem and found solution for me
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798465/vite-manifest-not-found-at-c-users-hp-example-app-public-build-manifest-json)

Update npm and node versions first and [install Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation) if you don't have it already.

Briefly what I've done after:

```
npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-vue
```

Then updated package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "vite build"
}
```

And

```
npm run build
```

Hope it will help ;)

Comment: I still can't get past this error when I run **npm run dev**

`dev
vite

file:///var/www/laravel-bootstrap/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:7
    await import('source-map-support').then((r) => r.default.install())
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
`

Answer (score 0):

Execute this update npm

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - &&\
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

link: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).