# User dropdown menu in Laravel breeze does not work [in fresh installation]

Tags: laravel, drop-down-menu, vite, breeze

I have installed new project in Laravel. After that, I installed Laravel Breeze package.

At first, when I  clicked on register link to go to /register Uri, I received the following error:
"**npm ERR! Missing script : 'build'** "

Then,  I followed the instruction in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72798465/vite-manifest-not-found-at-c-users-hp-example-app-public-build-manifest-json" which says to install "**vite**"  and "**laravel-vite-plugin**" and then update package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    }
```

I did them. Then I ran "**npm run build**". By doing them, Register and Login works perfectly. I could log in successfully. After login,  I redirected in /dashboard Uri.

But, in "*dashboard*",  when **I clicked on the users avatar (my name title)** in the top right corner , **drop down menu did not work**. The drop down menu supposed to be opened with logout link inside it, but it did not open.

I installed another project and repeated the above process again and  again, but drop down menu did not work. My **app.blade.php** includes **@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])**

I even included JQuery script to the **app.blade.php**, but It did not work too.

What can I do ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that **It is not enough** to have **@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])** in **app.blade.php**.

You should manually **add these two** to **app.blade.php** as well:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I did this and the problem solved .

Comment: I'm having the same problem, although after including it in the app.blade.php, I get a console error telling me it can't find the file. In my public folder, I have an assets folder and in these 2 i have a dynamic css/js file. How is your structure?

Comment: to have have 'css/app.css' and 'js/app.js', you should run "npm run serve" in terminal.

Comment: to have have 'css/app.css' and 'js/app.js', you should run "npm run serve" in terminal. you should Not have 'asset' folder. The term asset(''js/app.js')  means the following  path: 'public/js/app.js'. The two files should be in public folder.